# insert sqlite row from php array

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite

So I am attempting to write a generic sqlite insert that can be used no matter how many items a row has.  This is for a single row, assumes all columns other than ID, which is set to autoincrementing integer, are assigned, and bindparam must be used.  I have been attempting it like so:

```
Table Quarterbacks
ID---firstName---lastName

public static function insert($table, $values)
{
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:testTable.sqlite');
    $inputString = implode(",", $values);
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into $table values (:value)");
    $statement->bindParam(':value', $inputString);
    $statement->execute();
}
$new = array("Steve", "Young");
Query::insert("Quarterbacks", $new);
```

The idea being that the table will now add a new row, increment the ID, and add Steve Young.  But I get the generic error that the prepare statement is false.  I know my pdo is connecting to the database, as other test methods work.  There's a lot of array related threads out there but it seems like they're much more complicated than what I'm trying to do.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with it treating the single string as invalid, but it also won't take an array of strings for values.

Edit:I'm starting to lean towards a compromise like bash, ie provide a large but not infinite amount of function parameters.  Also open to the ...$ style but I feel like that ends up with the same problem as now.

I was able to get this to work

```
$name = "('daunte' , 'culpepper')";
$cats = "('firstName', 'lastName')";
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into $table" .$cats ." values" .$name);
$statement->execute();
```

But not this

```
$name = "('reggie' , 'wayne')";
$cats = "('firstName', 'lastName')";
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into $table:cats values:name");
$statement->bindParam(':cats', $cats);
$statement->bindParam(':name', $name);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: I think you have to do a select on the table itself to get the column names into an array, and then bind that similarly within your prepare insert statement.

Comment: Can you explain the restriction that bindParam must be used? It could be done more simply by passing the parameters as an argument to execute().

Comment: Also, just to be sure, are you trying to insert all the values in the `$values` array into a single column, or each value into a separate column?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I added an edit to make it clearer, but it is each value in a separate column.  Unfortunately the lack of bindParam on anything besides a select query gets an automatic assignment grade of 0 for this prof.